# imagettftext and the euro sign

Tags: php, utf-8, gd, imagettftext

I'm using imagettftext to generate a image (I've tried imagefttext as well) but I cannot display the EURO Sign. Look at how it makes it! The font is Myriad and in Photoshop the sign looks fine.

[image: Problem with Euro SIGN]

Comment: How you write EURO ? &euro; ? &#20AC;? € ?

Comment: $euro=chr(8364); OR $euro=chr(128);

Comment: I've tried both chr and both &#, and the euro sign as well.

Comment: $euro=utf8_decode(html_entity_decode('€',ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8'));

Comment: @red eyes dev, now I see a "?"

Comment: Sure you are charset UTF-8 ?
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: Does the font you are using have the euro character?

Comment: @red eyes dev.. it's an image, not a HTML!

Comment: @Garry If I can see it in Photoshop and other programs then I would assume so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just make an image of a euro sign (with Photoshop) and substitute it with GD.

Not really a solution but at least something that works.

Comment: That's actually what I did. Thanks :)