# GD2 Fonts locking on Windows/Apache

Tags: php, apache, fonts, gd

I have a PHP script that uses GD2 to create an image. It uses a TrueTypeFont file to generate text in the image with `imagettftext` (and `imagettfbbox`).
This script can be run on both Windows and Linux machines so I decided to copy a TTF file from the Windows/Fonts directory into the source-code, else I wouldn't know where to look for it.
I'm not at all happy with this solution but I don't know of a better one.

The real problem though is that on Windows/Apache the font file gets locked after it's been used once. The only way to unlock it is to restart Apache. The locking is a problem because I can't delete the file when I want to, which is especially annoying if you're using a version system.

So my problem has 3 solutions:

- Is there a way to avoid locking of font files (in source code/webroot) on Windows/Apache?
- Or is there a way to avoid copying the font file and use a native available TrueTypeFont? (OS independent if at all possible, likely hosts are Windows and Linux - Mac, not so much)
- Or is there a way to avoid using a TrueTypeFont and still get pretty (aliased) text with PHP GD2?

--

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.1.9
T1Lib Support   enabled
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPG Support     enabled
PNG Support     enabled
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support     enabled
```

Comment: I encountered the same problem few years ago, but don't recall how I solved it. I'll go through my archive HDD's tonight and see if I can find the code for it, but can't recall whether it was just a work around for the locks or an actual solution to prevent it.

Comment: Please do! I'd very much like to award the bounty than have it go down the drain ^^

Comment: @Frits van Campen I am afraid I am gonna have to dissapoint you. There was no solution in my previous project, instead I ended up creating a copy in the OS tmp folder with the contents of the font file. I had done quite a bit of research on it back then, and unless anything has changed since then, the problem is that the FreeType library opens a font handler and it won't close it again. Had this bug link commented in there http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=24450. If you don't want to go with the temp file solution I went with, I suggest you try and go with your other 2 options.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. At least it helps to know someone else spent time on it and couldn't find a solution ('no solution' is also an answer to my question). I will look into the temp-file workaround. If anyone has any ideas regarding the 2 other options feel free to share! I'd love to award this bounty.

Comment: Just curious, are you using a server that has a maintenance (restart) schedule? There might be a workaround along those lines

Comment: Uhh yea, the schedule is restart never :D

Comment: @Niklas : Could the bug have been intentional?? Leaving the handler open and using the same handler repeatingly, so as to not repeat the calls... that does not sound like a bad idea for the repeatingly used fonts =) Though not having the option to close it is a bad one.

Comment: @Pico.creator certainly doesn't sound intentional, as it doesn't function like that on UNIX environments.

Comment: @Niklas : icic, cause i was wondering is there someway, to get the file handle used, and close it at the end of the session. Assuming it is a file handle, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is a combination of suggestions. I checked StackOverflow policy on splitting bounties and it's not possible. The bounty must be awarded to a single comprehensive answer. I would like to split my bounty to all the people who replied / commented here, if there is an alternative way please contact me.

I didn't have much luck with the .gdf fonts, I can't really find any good looking fonts. It did point me in the direction of `imagestring` which can draw text without the need of any font file (gdf or ttf) - see the php doc. The 'default' font is just some monospace font which isn't very pretty but it serves nicely as a fallback.

To avoid the .ttf locking I will attempt to find the OS font folder and load the font from there. This has been tested on *my* Windows development machine. If the .ttf file can't be found it will use the native font fallback from `imagestring`.

I've chosen an Object-Oriented approach to make an abstraction on how the text is written to the image.

```
abstract class TextWriter {

    public static function getInstance() {
        $osName = php_uname( 's' );

        if (strtoupper(substr($osName, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
            $path = 'C:/Windows/Fonts/';
        } else if (strtoupper(substr($osName, 0, 5)) === 'LINUX') {
            $path = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/';
        } else if (strtoupper(substr($osName, 0, 7)) === 'FREEBSD') {
            $path = '/usr/local/lib/X11/fonts/TrueType';
        }
        if (is_dir($path) && is_file($path . "/arial.ttf")) {
            return new TTFTextWriter($path . "/arial.ttf");
        }
        return new NativeTextWriter();
    }

    abstract public function get_dimenions($string);
    abstract public function write_text($img_resource, $x, $y, $text, $color);

}

class TTFTextWriter extends TextWriter {

    private $ttf_file;
    private $fontsize = 10;

    public function __construct($ttf_file) {
        $this->ttf_file = $ttf_file;
    }

    public function get_dimenions($text) {
        $dimenions = imagettfbbox($this->fontsize, 0, $this->ttf_file, $text);
        return array($dimenions[2], abs($dimenions[5] - $dimenions[3]));
    }

    public function write_text($img_resource, $x, $y, $text, $color) {
        imagettftext($img_resource, $this->fontsize, 0, $x, $y, $color, $this->ttf_file, $text);
    }

}

class NativeTextWriter extends TextWriter {

    private $fontsize = 3;  // number between 1-5 see manual for imagestring
    private $text_width = 7;  // corresponds to $fontsize 3
    private $text_height = 15;  // corresponds to $fontsize 3

    public function get_dimenions($text) {
        return array(strlen($text) * $this->text_width, $this->text_height);
    }

    public function write_text($img_resource, $x, $y, $text, $color) {
        imagestring($img_resource, $this->fontsize, $x, $y - $this->text_height, $text, $color);
    }
}
```

Use like:

```
$writer = TextWriter::getInstance();

$dimenions = $writer->get_dimenions($text);
$width = $dimenions[0];
$height = $dimenions[1];
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 1, 1, 1);

$writer->write_text($im, 0, 0, $text, $black);
header('Content-Type: image/gif');

imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: :) no biggie: as long as the bounty dun go to waste, being split to half and given to the highest vote, losing 250 to nothing... :p consolation is to 1up all the answers haha. Maybe it can be a suggestion to accept multiple answers and split the bounty. After all in programing, there may be more then 1 method to do a specified job, without the 2 method being superior to another :p

Answer (score 1):

#### Why not using the library-defined font path?

From the [`imagettftext()` docs](http://php.net/function.imagettftext), you can use the library font path:

> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename along a **library-defined font path**.

See the [`gd_info()` page](http://www.php.net/function.gd-info) to find out which ttf library your windows php version is using. Then check the according library documentation what the font-path is.

Using TTFs from the fontpath might have the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is just a really obscure way of including the font file. Is there an OS-specific default? Is there a way of checking which font files exist? I want this script to work always, even on hosts where I don't have a lot of control over the environment. Which it currently does of course.

Comment: That's a bit like using a shotgun to kill a mosquito, no? And I don't want a dependency to imagemagick since it's far less common than gd2. I'm hoping there just is a 'proper' way to deal with fonts in gd2.

Comment: Well, I didn't wanted to sound rude. Consult the manual of the lib you use with GD2 to deal with fonts to learn more about font paths.

Comment: ^ that is what I got from the manual. Which doesn't help me at all. I don't want a fancy way to include my font file. I want to prevent locking of the font file. If you know of a way then please provide a code example. I'm willing to put a high bounty on this. This is a bit of trivial feature for me so I don't have the time to actually go about checking a solution on any permutation of environments, but it is important enough to me to reward a considerable bounty. I'm not asking someone to solve the problem, I want the experience of someone who has had this problem and solved it.

Comment: Which TTF library are you actually using?

Comment: You mean the TTF file? I think I'm using a TTF file I 'borrowed' from TCPDF. I'm using arial.ttf. Either that I took the file from Windows/Fonts. Feel free to berate me on that. I have absolutely no clue.

Comment: No, I mean the TTF software library that is used by the GD2 PHP module you are using. See the `gd_info()` link in my answer.

Comment: I put the output of my development machine in my question. This is fairly irrelevant though as I stated that I want this solution to work in any environment (so long as there is GD with truetype support). Why is this relevant?

Comment: Well as it might have helped you to learn where to properly setup places for files of which you report you don't know and your's then get locked. I can only assume that some file pointer is not closed hence making windows mark the file as locked. Never experienced such a problem and it can be even a misconfiguration of the operating system on which the script runs as well and must not be the script or libraries used itself. If you're able to, gather the information which handles / processes are blocking the file.

Comment: Like I said .. Apache locks the font file.

Comment: How is PHP invoked by your apache server?

Comment: I have no idea. To my knowledge it's not running in fast-cgi mode if that matters.

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to solve the problem, but I don't think we'll get there by randomly poking at stuff. Like I said, there must be someone out there who has also encountered this problem and either has a solution, or is stuck like me.

Comment: It's not randomly, but to locate the part that is locking the file. As you already know that one of apache's processes is locking the file, next step to check is which part exactly is causing the file-lock. If you're running on fcgi you can kill the fcgi spawn process and check if the file is still locked. If not, then PHP was still locking the file - not apache. You can kill the php-fcgi spawn process w/o restarting apache. I think you have the tools at hand as you already identified the process handle of the file lock. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced such an issue with GD but on a *Debian* distro. I found two solutions that might lead to *wamp* solutions as well :

**a**- install the bundle graphic library from dotdeb.org libgd i/o native php GD library and recompile the sources the *with-freetype* option,

or

**b**- install *imagick* instead of GD

I applied solution "a" successfully on a *debian* distro.

Here are some links I used at that time :
[imagick on wamp](http://valokuva.org/outside-blog-content/imagick-windows-builds/php53/imagick-2.3.0-dev/)
[howtoforge](http://www.howtoforge.com/recompiling-php5-with-bundled-support-for-gd-on-ubuntu)
[drupal](http://drupal.org/node/134331#comment-1120427)
[libgd](http://www.libgd.org/FAQ_PHP#How_do_I_get_gd_to_work_with_PHP.3F)
[boutell](http://www.boutell.com/gd/manual2.0.15.html#buildgd)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly recompiling PHP is not an option for me, and in my environment _with-freetype_ is already enabled so I doubt it would solve my specific problem. _ImageMagick_ is also not an option for me as most hosts don't have it enabled. I'm looking for a very generic solution to what I think is a bit of a bug.

Comment: Did you confirm that the font-locking also occurs on _Debian_ machines?

Comment: @Frits van Campen : I has this issue quite a while ago. I can't remember whether the use of these GD functions was buggy because of the GD lib itself and/or of the fonts locking. But I remember that I also had to import an additional TTF fonts on top of recompiling a bundled GD lib. Good luck as I also remember the big headhaches for this @%$.. issue.

Answer (score 0):

I do know a workaround that is a bit laborious. A similar solution as I suggested: [imagettftext-and-the-euro-sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226231/imagettftext-and-the-euro-sign/6312175#6312175).

In my case this could work as I'm really just looking for a way to generate some very simple images with text. It averts my problem but of course doesn't fix the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using GD fonts (.gdf) will solve the issue with the files getting locked. You can move/rename/delete them as you wish even after using them.

They aren't quite as pretty as .ttf fonts, but with a bit of tinkering with gaussian blur you can get them to look almost identical to their ttf counterparts in terms of anti aliasing. Sample text with arial:

[image]

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 200);

$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

imagefill ( $im , 0 , 0 ,$bg );
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imageantialias ( $im ,true );

$font = imageloadfont('arial-reg-20.gdf');

imagestring($im, $font, 10, 10, 'Hello world!', $textcolor);

imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR,10);
imagestring($im, $font, 10, 10, 'Hello world!', $textcolor);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR,1);
// Output the image
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: How would I go about finding or creating a .gdf file? It doesn't nearly as straightforward as I'd hoped :(

Comment: There are plenty of fonts available already, doing a search for .gdf fonts or arial.gdf for example will give you quite a lot of results. Likewise, there are quite a few different tools available for converting ttf files into gdf.

Comment: Yes, but there can be big-endian vs. little-ending encoding issues for the .gdf file. I have no idea what kind of machine this is going to run on.

Comment: @Frits van Campen you mentioned in your question that you only needed it for Windows/Linux (not Mac), so thought it wouldn't be an issue as they both are under little-endian.

Comment: I see, well that would make it loads easier :) I'll try this on monday.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, my apologies if this does not work. For i could only test them on WAMP. Where this bug (according to online research) does not affect.

**1)** Make sure to `imagedestroy($im);`

**2)** To get the font folders for either platforms

```
<?php
function fontFolder() {
    $osName = php_uname( 's' );

    if (strtoupper(substr($osName, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
        return '/Windows/Fonts/';
    }

    if (strtoupper(substr($osName, 0, 5)) === 'LINUX') {
        return '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/';
    }

    if (strtoupper(substr($osName, 0, 7)) === 'FREEBSD') {
        //This is not tested
        return '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/';
    }
}

echo fontFolder();
?>
```

*Note this list of OS is not fully extensive, you may need to add / modify it for your needs.

**3) [NOT RECOMMENDED]** Persudo-"Cache" the font files : And leave the cache to clear on its own after the first run on server reset. That way, while the fonts gets 'locked' it is only the cache copy that gets locked. Not the actual working files you are 'playing' with. Hence it does not affect your work cycle. The files does get deleted eventually, when the system is rebooted, and they are 'cleared to delete'.

**EDIT:** Note that you can always point the folder to a tmp folder in a linux setup, should work somewhat the same.

```
<?php
/**
Recursive delete, with a 'file/folder igonore option'
[$ignoreArra] : An array or a single string, to ignore delete (folder or file)
[$ignoreRootFolder] : Ignores the starting root folder
**/
function recursiveDelete($str, $ignoreArray = null, $ignoreRootFolder = false){
    if($str == '' || $str == '/')   {   //Prevent accidental 'worse case scenerios'
        return false;   
    }

    //Ensures it working as an array
    if($ignoreArray == null) {
        $ignoreArray = array(); //new Array
    }
    if(!is_array( $ignoreArray ) ) {
        $ignoreArray = array( $ignoreArray );
    }

    if(is_file($str)){
        if(in_array( $str, $ignoreArray ) ) {
            return false;
        } //else
        return @unlink($str);
    }
    elseif(is_dir($str)){
        $scan = glob(rtrim($str,'/').'/*');
        $chk = true;
        foreach($scan as $index=>$path) {
            $buf = recursiveDelete($path, $ignoreArray);
            if( $buf == false ) {
                $chk = false;
            }
        }

        if( in_array( $str, $ignoreArray ) || $chk == false || $ignoreRootFolder ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return @rmdir($str);
        }
    }   else    {
        return false;
    }
}

define('fontCacheFolder', './font_cache/');
function fontCache($fontFolder, $fontFile) {
    $cachedFile = fontCacheFolder.$fontFile;
    recursiveDelete( fontCacheFolder , $cachedFile , true);
    if( is_file( $cachedFile ) ) {
        return $cachedFile;
    }
    copy( $fontFolder.$fontFile, $cachedFile);
    return $cachedFile;
}

echo fontCache('./', 'arial.ttf');
?>
```

**4) UPDATED:** Just leave all your fonts in one folder, and only do deletes of what is not needed before the actual / final deployment of your server. =) Just leave the font folder alone.

Example shared server structure.

```
www/root
   +----- fonts
   +----- app A
   +----- site B
```

Hence for any website / application nested in the root www folder, to access the shared font folder just use

```
'../fonts/fontName.ttf'
```

Hence, whenever you make changes and updates to the app / site, you save the trouble of conflicts in fonts.

Comment: 1) I checked that, shouldn't matter though as PHP should clean up all resources when shutting down.

Comment: 2) Yea, I was afraid of that. It is the nicest solution though as I wont have to copy any font files. I might just go for this :/

Comment: 3) I'm not sure what you mean by this. I could perhaps cache the font file in the server tmp dir. I can't cache it anywhere near the webroot since I wont to be able to clear it whenever I want.

Comment: 4) I don't know what you mean? I currently only have one font and it's always needed.

Comment: @Frits van Campen, 3) i meant a pesudo-cahce. Its in the code =P

and for 4) -.-" Then why are you having trouble deleting / etc... You can just leave it as it is

Comment: @Frits van Campen, i vote for option 2) also, UNLESS you are using custom fonts. =X

Comment: I'm having trouble deleting because something (probably Apache) keeps a lock on the font files. This is particularly annoying if you want to upgrade or clean up the application. I don't see how 3 or 4 would help.

Comment: If thats a case, just create a dedicated font folder on the drive that never needs to be cleaned out. Cause this seems to be a problem limited to APACHE. I guess pretty much 3) Would be useless judging from your explaination though.

You can always have a central font folder in your server for all apps / etc. If lets say your server is shared among different apps / sites, you can have a shared font folder in its parent =)

Comment: @Frits van Campen : The point of having a centralize font folder, is so that you will never need to clean it out. See the edit at 4) for more details...

Comment: I see. Well this wont do me any good as there is typically only one application per server. This could be a solution if I only had one server with many applications. But thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @Frits van Campen: 4) it still can be applicable, if you standardize all future font for GD2 to take this folder approach, it will work with one or many apps... Shared or dedicated servers... It saves some hassle as a standard. Imagine the font folder as a php library package :) for GD2 on any app. The point is to externalize the font from your app project development. Putting it in a folder that you Csv / software versioning for specific project has no control / no conflicts. Hence becoming a footnote in your development... Bugs like these ain't worth getting stuck on :)

Comment: @Frits van Campen : besides, it is relatively easy to set your web access to a folder / one app. With rewrite rules / etc... In fact I do this to all my servers, as I use the admin space above to backup / test stuff / etc... :) though some calls this bad practice on live servers :( I still do it anyway